# Incorporate JQuery Fade effect into removing and adding classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this code that changes the classes that apply to an element and those classes contain a background image. i want to make the images fade in and out as opposed to just switching.

```
$(document).ready(
function(){
var toggleImage = function(){
    if($(".home").hasClass("home1")){
        $(".home").removeClass("home1").addClass("home2");  
        console.log("First IF");
            }
    else if($(".home").hasClass("home2")){
        $(".home").removeClass("home2").addClass("home3");
        console.log("Second IF");
    }
    else if($(".home").hasClass("home3")){
        $(".home").removeClass("home3").addClass("home1");
        console.log("Third IF");

    }
    console.log("End of the conditionals");
}

console.log("Outside of the conditionals");

setInterval(toggleImage, 5000)

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking is not possible directly. You will need to use CSS3 fade effect(http://webdesign.about.com/od/css3tutorials/a/fade-in-and-out-with-css3.htm)